# How to parse metadata from Clojure namespace form?

Tags: clojure

If I have a namespace form, how do I extract the metadata map from it? For example:

```
(some-function '(ns ^{:doc "docstring"})) => {:doc "docstring"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reader metadata introduced with `^` is attached to the next form to be read in.

The quoted form in your example is malformed as Clojure code (that is, without even considering it being an `ns` form in particular), because the metadata map has nothing to attach itself to. A fixed version might be `(ns ^{:doc "docstring"} foo)`. Here `foo` becomes the (mandatory) "name" argument to `ns`.

Now you can simply extract the symbol `foo` from the `ns` form using, say, `second` and read its metadata map:

```
(-> '(ns ^{...} foo) second meta)
```

Note that docstrings for namespaces can be provided in the form of an extra argument to `ns`:

```
(ns foo
  "foo's docstring"
  ...)
```

Also, an additional "attribute map" may be provided as an extra argument (following the docstring if one is given in this form, immediately after the name symbol otherwise). This attribute map will be merged with the metadata of the name symbol and may of course include the key `:doc`.

So if you want to obtain "the docstring, if any", you'll need to look at the metadata on the name symbol, the form immediately following it (if any; check if it's a string or a map) and possibly one more form (if a docstring is given as the second argument to `ns`; check if it's a map).